# Установка положения скрола вниз , с учетом пагинации при скроле верх

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ребят помогите решить проблему.

Я делаю чат на React и мне надо что бы при выборе текущего канала и или при переключении канала скрол был в нижней границе, + ещё что бы была пагинация при скроле верх.

Положение скрола при переключении и при установке текущего канала я сделал, и пагинацию я тоже сделал.
НО проблема заключаеться в том что при переключении канала скрол изначать становиться в значение 0 а потом присваиваеться значение низа , и в момент когда scrollTop равен 0 срабатывает условие подгрузки сообщений.
Как мне это сделать как при переключении канала заблокировать пагинацию и что бы пагинация срабатывала только при скроле блока сообщений.

Компонент ChatPanel отвечает за отображение сообщений и отправку

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
 
import Messages from "../Messages/Messages";
import {useRedux} from "../../hook/useRedux";
import InfoChannel from "../InfoChannel/InfoChannel";
import SendMessages from "../SendMessages/SendMessages";
import st from './ChatPanel.module.scss';
import Connect from "../../UI/Connect/Connect";
import ChannelAPI from "../../http/channelAPI";
import {useService} from "../../hook/useService";
import {ScrollToBottom} from "../modules/ScrollToBottom/ScrollToBottom";
 
const ChatPanel = (
    {
        websocket
        , isConnectUserInChannel
    }) => {
 
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
    const {channel, user, message} = useRedux();
    const messagesListRef = useRef(null);
    const {ChannelService, MessageService} = useService();
 
 
    const handlerScroll = (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        const rect = messagesListRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
 
        // console.log(
        //     target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight - target.scrollTop
        // )
 
        // const isScrollTop =  ((target.scrollHeight + target.clientHeight) + target.scrollTop - window.innerHeight) <= rect.bottom;
        // const isScrollTop = rect.top >= 0 && rect.top <= 90 && !isFetching
        // const isScrollTop = (target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight - target.scrollTop) > 100
        const isScrollTop = target.scrollTop === 0;
 
 
        // if (Math.round(rect.bottom) >= Math.round(rect.height)) {
        // if (rect.top === 100 && !isFetching) {
        //     // if (scrolledRef.current?.scrollHeight - (scrolledRef.current?.clientHeight + window.innerHeight) + 200 < rect.top) {
        //     // if (container.scrollTop === container.scrollHeight - container.clientHeight) {
        if (isScrollTop) {
            setIsFetching(true);
        }
    }
 
    const ConnectUserToChannel = async () => {
        await ChannelAPI.addUserToChannelAPI(user.currentUser.id, channel.currentChannelId)
            .then(channel =>
                ChannelService.addNewChannel(channel)
            );
 
        await ChannelAPI.fetchOneChannel(channel.currentChannelId)
            .then(channel =>
                ChannelService.addCurrentChannel(channel)
            );
    }
 
    const fetchDataChannel = async () => {
        if (message.messages[channel.currentChannelId]) {
            console.log(`fetching`);
            const page = message.messages[channel.currentChannelId].page
            const channelF = await ChannelAPI.fetchOneChannel(channel.currentChannelId, page);
 
            MessageService.messagePagination(channel.currentChannelId, channelF.messages);
            MessageService.setPageMessage(channel.currentChannelId, page + 1);
        }
    }
 
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFetching) {
            fetchDataChannel()
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
                .finally(() => setIsFetching(false));
        }
    }, [isFetching]);
 
    if (!channel.currentChannel) {
        return (
            <section className={st.chatPanel}></section>
        );
    }
 
 
    return (
        <section
            className={st.chatPanel}
            id="chat__right"
        >
            <div className={st.chatPanel__wrapper}>
                <InfoChannel/>
 
                <ScrollToBottom
                    onScroll={handlerScroll}
                    isConnectUserInChannel={isConnectUserInChannel}
                >
                    <Messages
                        ref={messagesListRef}
                    />
                </ScrollToBottom>
 
                {
                    isConnectUserInChannel ? (
                        <SendMessages
                            websocket={websocket}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <Connect
                            onClick={ConnectUserToChannel}
                        >
                            Подключится
                        </Connect>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
 
export default ChatPanel;
```

Компонент ScrollToBottom отвечает за прокрутку до нижней границы

```
import React, {forwardRef, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import st from './ScrollToBottom.module.scss';
import {useRedux} from "../../../hook/useRedux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
 
const ScrollToBottom = forwardRef((
    {
        isConnectUserInChannel
        , ...props
    }, ref) => {
    const bottomRef = useRef(null);
    const rootClasses = [st.scrollable, st.scrollableY];
    const {channel, message} = useRedux();
 
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (bottomRef.current) {
            bottomRef.current?.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'auto'
                , block: 'end'
            })
        }
    };
 
    useEffect(() => {
        scrollToBottom();
    }, [channel.currentChannel, isConnectUserInChannel]);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        scrollToBottom();
    }, [message.messages.length]);
 
    return (
        <div
            {...props}
            className={rootClasses.join(' ')}
            ref={ref}
        >
            {props.children}
            <div ref={bottomRef}></div>
        </div>
    );
});
 
ScrollToBottom.propTypes = {
    isCurrentChannel: PropTypes.bool,
}
 
export {
    ScrollToBottom
};
```